# java - button not added

Tags: java, javafx, radio-button

I need some help I created this pizza ordering system that adds toppings to a list when you press the radio button and then add the size of the pizza to a list. The only thing I need now is the order button. I believe the code is right but for some reason the button is not there. Not sure if I did something wrong. The button is labeled place order. Thank you for help
here is the code:

```
package loan;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import loan.pizzas.OrderHandler;

class User {
    private StringProperty order = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public String getOrder() {
        return order.get();
    }

    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order.set(order);
    }

    public StringProperty orderProperty() {
        return order;
    }
}

public class demo extends Application {

    private User user = new User();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Pizza System");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("place order");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
             public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                 System.out.println("Order has been placed.");
                }
        });



        RadioButton tomatoButton = new RadioButton("Tomato");
        RadioButton pepperButton = new RadioButton("Pepper");
        RadioButton mushroomButton = new RadioButton("Mushrooms");

        ChoiceBox<String> pizzaType = new ChoiceBox<String>();
        pizzaType.getItems().addAll("", "Small", "Medium", "Large");
        pizzaType.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

        HBox topHBox = new HBox(15.0, tomatoButton, pepperButton, mushroomButton, pizzaType);

        // create custom Binding that binds selection of radio buttons and choice box
        StringBinding orderBinding = createOrderBinding(tomatoButton.selectedProperty(), pepperButton.selectedProperty(), mushroomButton.selectedProperty(), pizzaType.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
        // bind orderBinding to orderProperty of User
        user.orderProperty().bind(orderBinding);

        TextArea orderArea = new TextArea();
        // bind orderProperty of User to textProperty of TextArea
        orderArea.textProperty().bindBidirectional(user.orderProperty());

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(topHBox);
        root.setCenter(orderArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    /**
     * Creates StringBinding between 4 provided arguments. Binding means that when value of one bound property is changed the whole binding is recomputed in computeValue method.
     * The value of computeValue is bound to User.orderProperty 
     */
    public StringBinding createOrderBinding(BooleanProperty tomato, BooleanProperty pepper, BooleanProperty mushroom, ReadOnlyObjectProperty<String> selectedPizzaType) {
        StringBinding binding = new StringBinding() {
            {
                // bind 4 provided properties.
                super.bind(tomato, pepper, mushroom, selectedPizzaType);
            }

            /* 
             * Fires each time bound property is modified. 
             */
            @Override
            protected String computeValue() {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Pizza content:\n");

                if (tomato.get())
                    sb.append("\tTomato\n");
                if (pepper.get())
                    sb.append("\tPepper\n");
                if (mushroom.get())
                    sb.append("\tMushroom\n");

                sb.append("Pizza type:\n").append("\t" + selectedPizzaType.get());
                return sb.toString();
            }
        };
        return binding;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I believe the code is right" The behavior is wrong, so the code should be wrong. Do not believe such a thing..

Comment: Shouldn't the button be "added" to somewhere to have it be shown?

Comment: you not adding `btn` .right?add it 
`HBox topHBox = new HBox(15.0, tomatoButton, pepperButton, mushroomButton, pizzaType,btn);`

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Fast Snail, you need to add the button to your HBox in order for it to appear in the Hbox. giving you all of the buttons seperated with the spacing you have specified.

Answer (score 0):

> You actually need to add the button to your HBox if you want it to appread in HBox.